# Azure - Simple JSON template and parameter file and yet still prompts for input

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-rm-template

In the Azure portal I have gone through the wizard to setup a new vNet virtual network. Before creating it I have downloaded the zip file package from the Azure portal with the JSON in it and cancelled the create

Using the 2 pieces of JSON (attached) that remain unchanged from Azure, I’m using a simple 2 line Powershell script…

```
$resourceGroupName = "RG-SBX-MYTEST"
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name deploy_vNet -TemplateFile "C:\Azure\vNet\template.json" -TemplateParameterFile "C:\Azure\vNet\parameters.json"
```

When it runs it prompts me for **nameFromTemplate** and **resourceGroupFromTemplate**, but all other values from the parameters.json file are respected… ???

```
cmdlet New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
(Type !? for Help.)
nameFromTemplate: vNet-SBX-MYTEST
resourceGroupFromTemplate: RG-SBX-MYTEST


DeploymentName          : deploy_vNet
ResourceGroupName       : RG-SBX-MYTEST
ProvisioningState       : Succeeded
Timestamp               : 19/02/2019 12:00:28
Mode                    : Incremental
TemplateLink            : 
Parameters              : 
                          Name             Type                       Value     
                          ===============  =========================  ==========
                          name             String                     vNet-SBX-MYTEST
                          resourceGroup    String                     RG-SBX-MYTEST
                          location         String                     westeurope
                          addressPrefix    String                     10.1.0.0/16
                          subnetName       String                     default   
                          subnetAddressPrefix  String                     10.1.0.0/24
                          enableDdosProtection  Bool                       False     

Outputs                 : 
DeploymentDebugLogLevel :
```

I don't understand what the issue is here? Please help, this is supposed to be simple right?? I'm not expecting two prompts for values the parameters file already has

Thanks in advance!

parameters.json file

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "name": {
            "value": "vNet-SBX-MYTEST"
        },
        "location": {
            "value": "westeurope"
        },
        "resourceGroup": {
            "value": "RG-SBX-MYTEST"
        },
        "addressPrefix": {
            "value": "10.1.0.0/16"
        },
        "subnetName": {
            "value": "default"
        },
        "subnetAddressPrefix": {
            "value": "10.1.0.0/24"
        },
        "enableDdosProtection": {
            "value": false
        }
    }
}
```

template.json file

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "resourceGroup": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "addressPrefix": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "subnetName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "subnetAddressPrefix": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "enableDdosProtection": {
            "type": "bool"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2018-08-01",
            "name": "[parameters('name')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "addressSpace": {
                    "addressPrefixes": [
                        "[parameters('addressPrefix')]"
                    ]
                },
                "subnets": [
                    {
                        "name": "[parameters('subnetName')]",
                        "properties": {
                            "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnetAddressPrefix')]"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "enableDdosProtection": "[parameters('enableDdosProtection')]"
            }
        }
    ] }
```

Comment: you dont even have those parameters in the template, so you are clearly doing something wrong, probably deploying wrong template

Comment: What you see is all I have, direct from the Azure portal

Comment: ah wait, i remembered, I haven't seen that in a while, i think its powershell acting weirdly, can you rename `name` and `resourcegroup` to something else? like add a prefix in both the template and parameters file? you can just drop resourcegroup parameter, it not even used

Comment: @4c74356b41 yes that worked. What's up with Powershell then? This is my first real experience in using Infrastructure as Code in Azure and so far I've lost a day! If its something I can do to fix Powershell that would be great

Comment: you can always come here and ask questions if you get stuck )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what is happening exactly, but I think powershell is being confused by the fact you are passing parameters called name and resourceGroup to the cmdlet and to the template, it really looks like a bug\edge case in the cmdlet. one thing you can do - just avoid calling you parameters like that, unfortunately.

for clarity: solution is to rename both parameters to something else, like resource_name and resource_group_name (although, the second one isnt even used)

ps. you can also raise an issue on Azure Powershell github: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues

Comment: Thanks, pretty funny if that is the case. I've only been using this 10 minutes and found a bug! Cheers!

Comment: UPDATE: This has been a bug since 2016 that Microsoft seem unwilling to fix. Amazingly simple but can't be bothered https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/2278